# Fading a 3D object into the background, using D3D9, SH3 & HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-9

I have a simple program that renders a couple of 3D objects, using DirectX 3D 9 and HLSL. I'm just starting off with HLSL, I have no experience with 3D rendering.

I am able to change the texture & color of the models and fade between two textures without problems, however I was wondering what the best way to simply fade a 3D object (blend it with the background) would be. I would assume that it wouldn't be done as fading between two textures (using `lerp`), since I want the object faded to the entire background, so there would be many different textures behind it.

I'm using the `LPD3DXEFFECT` as my effect class, `DrawIndexedPrimitive` as the drawing function in each pass, and I only have a single pass. I'm also using Shader Model 3, as this is an older project.

The only way that I thought it possible would be to simply get the color of the pixel before you apply any changes, and then do calculations on it with the color of the texture of the model to attain a faded pixel. However, after looking over the internet, it does not appear that it's actually possible to get the color of a pixel before doing anything to it with HLSL.

Is it even possible to do something like this using HLSL? Am I missing something that could assist me here?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long grind, I finally found a very good workaround for my problem, and I will try to explain my understanding of it for anyone else that has a smillar issue. Thanks to Alexander Stewart for suggesting that there may be an in-built way to do it.

---

**Method Description**

Instead of taking care of the background fade in the HLSL pixel shader, there is another way to do it, using a method called **Frame Buffer Alpha Blending** (full MS Docs documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/frame-buffer-alpha).

The basic idea behind this method is to provide a simple way of blending a given pixel that is to be rendered, with the existing pixel on the screen. There is a formula that is followed: `FinalColor = ObjectPixelColor * SourceBlendFactor + BackgroundPixelColor * DestinationBlendFactor`, all of these "variables" being groups of 4 float values, in the format (R, G, B, A).

---

**How I Implemented it**

Before doing anything with the actual shaders, in my Visual Studio C++ file I have to pass a few flags to my render device (I used `LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9` as my device class). I had to set render states for both `D3DRS_SRCBLEND` and `D3DRS_DESTBLEND`, which are reffering to `ObjectPixelColor` and `DestinationBlendFactor` respectivelly in the formula above. These will be my factors that will be multiplying each one of my object and background pixel colors. There are many possible values that can be assigned to `D3DRS_SRCBLEND` and `D3DRS_DESTBLEND`, full list is available in the MS Docs link above, but in order to achieve what I wanted to (simply a way to fade an object into the background with an alpha number going from 0 to 1), I figured out the flags should be like this: `SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA); SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);`.

After setting these flags, before passing through my shaders & rendering, I just needed to set one more flag: `SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);`. I was also able to alternate between `TRUE` and `FALSE` here without changing anything else with no rendering problems (although my project was very simple, it will probably cause issues on larger projects). You can then pass any arguments you want, such as the alpha number, to the HLSL shader as a global variable (I did it using `SetValue()`).

Going back to my HLSL shader, after these changes, passing a color `float4` variable taken from the `tex2D()` function from my pixel shader with an alpha value between 0 and 1 yielded the correct alpha, provided there aren't other issues (another issue that I had but hadn't realized at the time was the fact that my transparent object was actually rendering before the background, so I can only reccomend to check the rendering order when working on rendering projects).

I'm sure there could have probably been a better way of implementing this with the latest DirectX, but my compiler only supports Shader Model 3 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're trying to simulate transparency instead of using built-in transparency.

If you're trying to get the color of the pixels behind the object and want to avoid using transparency, I'd start by trying to use the last rendered frame as a texture, then reference that texture in your current shader. There may be some way to do it within the same frame - to force all other rendering to go first, then handle the one object - but I don't know it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:

By "built-in transparency", do you mean the 4th element of the color variable passed to the HLSL shader by the application (color.a)? If so, I already tried changing the value, but nothing happened, which lead me to believe that I have to implement such transparency myself.

That second option sounds very interesting, do you know a way of "saving" a rendered frame? I'm currently using "Begin()" and "End()" functions on a "LPD3DXEFFECT" variable to draw on the screen, what would the function to save a frame be?

Comment: Also for the record, this isn't being done in an existing video game engine such as Unity, but in Visual Studio.

Comment: I added some more details into the original question, could it also be because I'm using "DrawIndexedPrimitive" to draw my objects? Could it be that it doesn't support transparency?